# How to use Framer Motion <AnimatePresence> and React Portals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

### Situation

I built a React **Modal** component using **React Portals** (see Docs above). Before unmounting the component when the close button is clicked, I want to run an `exit` animation with Framer Motion using **AnimatePresence**. Unfortunately, I can't make it work and need help.

### Links

- [React Portals Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)
- [Framer Motion AnimatePresence Docs](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/)
- [React Modal File](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-feather-fdg1i?file=/src/App.js)

### What I tried

> I added `exit={{ opacity: 0 }}` to a child of `<RenderModal/>`. The entering animation using `initial` and `animate` worked as expected.

1. Wrap `<AnimatePresence>` around modal-root element

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<AnimatePresence>
  <div id="modal-root"></div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

2. Wrap as child of modal-root

> Error: Target container requires a DOM element

```js
<div id="modal-root">
  <AnimatePresence></AnimatePresence>
</div>
```

3. Wrap around the component element

```js
const Modal = ({
    title,
    footer,
    children,
  }) => {
   <AnimatePresence>
    {isVisible
      && (
        <RenderModal
          title={title}
          footer={footer}
          hide={hide}
        >
          {children}
        </RenderModal>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  };
```

4. Wrap around the used Component

```js
return (
  <>
    <Button onClick={show}>Open Modal</Button>
    <AnimatePresence>
      <Modal {...args}></Modal>
    </AnimatePresence>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 8):

Hello I think might be late.
but I solve with this code

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

interface ModalWrapperProps {
    children: ReactNode;
    isShowing: boolean;
}

const ModalWrapper = ({ children, isShowing }: ModalWrapperProps) =>
    ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
            {isShowing && children}
        </AnimatePresence>,
        document.body
    );

export default ModalWrapper;
```

I inspired below post

https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-animated-toasts-in-react/

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to include a `key` prop for the conditionally rendered element? I don't see it in your code snippets.

From [the docs](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#usage):

> Child motion components must each have a unique key prop so AnimatePresence can track their presence in the tree.