Exit animations not working while using `AnimatePresence`
I'm having trouble getting exit animations to fire. I've looked through as many questions as I could find, but haven't been able to solve it yet. Hoping there's some help available!
Sharing some redacted code below. My exit animations also aren't working as expected.
Here is my custom Toast implementation Toast.tsx:
<ToastPrimitive.Provider
      swipeDirection="right"
      label={label ?? 'Toast notification'}
    >
      <ToastPrimitive.Root
        {...props}
        ...many props here...
      >
        <motion.div
          layout
          initial={{ x: 333, opacity: 1 }}
          animate={{ x: 0 }}
          exit={{
            opacity: 0,
            zIndex: -1,
            height: 0,
            width: 0,
            transition: {
              opacity: {
                duration: 0.3,
              },
            },
          }}
          transition={{
            type: 'spring',
            mass: 1,
            damping: 33,
            stiffness: 222,
          }}
          key={id}
        >
          ...many components here...
        </motion.div>
      </ToastPrimitive.Root>
      <ToastPrimitive.Viewport className={toastViewport()} />
    </ToastPrimitive.Provider>

Here's where the component(s) actually get rendered:
const ToastContainer = ({ toasts, onDismissToast }: ToastContainerProps) => {
  return createPortal(
    <AnimatePresence>
      {toasts.map(({ id, ariaLabel, ...args }) => (
        <ToastComponent
          key={id}
          id={id}
          aria-label={ariaLabel}
          onOpenChange={() => onDismissToast(id)}
          {...args}
        />
      ))}
    </AnimatePresence>,
    document.body,
  ) as ReactNode;
};

Initial animations work really nice but it just drops off the page after the duration, no exit animations.
Had a couple theories:

maybe createPortal is causing something to happen?

hmm maybe not, based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328100/9878332


I found another similar implementation: https://buildui.com/recipes/animated-toast

key difference between this one and mine is that mine wraps ToastPrimitive.Provider with AnimatePresence, whereas theirs has the provider outside of AnimatePresence. I tried doing something similar but that meant having to use AnimatePresence within the Toast component itself (Toast.tsx above), which would also break it based on the comments above, so I don't think that's the cause of the issue.



